# Import module and return variables to Spyder environment

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I'd like to know if it's possible to import a custom module, e.g. debug_funcs.py, and have it return some of the variables to the Spyder environment?

I define a few functions in the above, and at the bottom I call the `__init__()` function that I want to return environment variables.  I then call `import debug_funcs` in Spyder (console or otherwise).

In debug_funcs.py:

```py
def __init__():
   out1 = something
   out2 = something else

   return out1, out2

out1, out2 = __init__()
```

I was hoping to import the module to save me selecting all the code and hitting F9, such that the history is more usable, and I'd like to have the variable available to inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the following to debug_funcs.py to have your variables pushed to the current console.

```
from IPython import get_ipython

ipython = get_ipython()
ipython.push({'out1': out1, 'out2': out2})
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks.  I didn't know about that option.  That certainly helps a lot.